# Azure Data Factory Analytics pricing

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Due to [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-using-azure-monitor#monitor-data-factory-metrics), in order to get activity-grain log events about ADF pipelines, I have to configure [Azure Data Factory Analytics](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/Microsoft.AzureDataFactoryAnalytics?src=azserv&tab=Reviews):

[image]

Without ADF Analytics I can get events only of pipeline grain, which doesn't solve my audit requirements.

*Is ADF Analytics free to use? If no - what is the pricing? Shall I be aware about any billing specific of Azure Marketplace?* Currently I can't find any pricing details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ADF Analytics is charged. The pricing is `0.25$ per 50,000 entities`. You can see the pricing via [Azure Pricing Calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?service=data-factory).

Add a screenshot for it:

[image]